# How to use rolling function to get yearly data mean?

Tags: python, time-series, rolling-computation

I have CO2 data from 1958 to present that I am trying to see the monthly fluctuations of. To do this, I want to use the rolling function to create another column in my data frame so that I can subtract this from the monthly totals to see the fluctuations. 
My data is weekly like 3/29/1958, 4/5/1958, etc.

I've never tried to use the rolling function before and I'm trying to figure it out.

So far, I've written

```
dfMaunaLoa = 
pd.read_csv('weekly_in_situ_co2_mlo.csv',skiprows=44,usecols= 
['Date','CO2'],index_col='Date',parse_dates=True)
dfMaunaLoa['Rolling_Mean'] = 
dfMaunaLoa['CO2'].rolling("365D").mean()
```

I can see that a column has been created in the data frame and has values, but I do not know if they're correct as I'm not sure what I should be expecting to see. I'm also not sure how to subtract this column from the other to get my final plot. I do not get any error messages.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to substract one column from the other you could do this:

```
dfMaunaLoa['substract_column'] = dfMaunaLoa['column_1'] - dfMaunaLoa['column_2']
```

and use in your plot